# VueJS - How to remove classes while building?

Tags: vue.js

I'm writing scoped SCSS. This creates like this html.

```
<nav data-v-8998d9f4 class="nav">
....
</nav>

.nav[data-v-8998d9f4] {
    ...
    width: 100%;
}
```

But I would like to remove class names while building. So should be like this:

```
<nav data-v-8998d9f4>
....
</nav>

[data-v-8998d9f4] {
    ...
    width: 100%;
}
```

Is there any way to do this? I choose my class names sloppy and I don't want them to appear. Also, classes are completely unnecessary when writing scoped.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible. Rather than removing the class names, you can try adopting a naming methodology like [BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/). Will help in a more readable markup too.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing this question and my first answer again i have to admit that my first answer was wrong.

This is actually a bad idea. When removing the selector all of the elements inside that component will have the same styling, because that data-hash attribute is the same for the whole component. Also as far as i know there is no way to modify the naming of scoped styling in vue.js

However if you want the freedom to change the naming of the generated classes you might want to use CSS modules instead of scoped styling.
Here is a good explanation about that: https://www.netguru.com/codestories/vue.js-scoped-styles-vs-css-modules
Also theres a section in the vue-cli documentation for that:
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#css-modules

Another alternative would be to use none of the above and instead go for something like BEM where you begin with your components name as the block. This way your style is scoped aswell and the readability is a lot better.

With my initial answer i have confused css modules with scoped styling, but for the record this is my initial answer:

Yes this is possible.

take a look at the following webpack config:

```
// webpack.config.js
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ... other rules omitted
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              // enable SCSS Modules
              modules: true,
              // customize generated class names
              localIdentName: '[local]_[hash:base64:8]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

source: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html#usage

localIdentName is what you are looking for. you could change this to '[hash:base64:8]'

However i personally think this makes your css unnecessarily verbose. Debugging something in the browser might be a pain like that.

Comment: I did and doesn't work. I run npm run dev and I can see the classes still. But *Debugging something in the browser might be a pain like that.* you're right about that.

Comment: After re-reading your question i've noticed you are using scss so you might want to change the config accordingly. This way it will most likely only work with plain css. Did you try that?

Comment: I tried your last edit and still doesn't work. Did you try your own?

Comment: Unfortunally i have confused scoped styling in vue.js with CSS Modules(popular in react) this only works for css modules, which are also usable in vue.js, but the syntax is more complicated. 

If you want to know more about css modules. here is a good explanation : https://www.netguru.com/codestories/vue.js-scoped-styles-vs-css-modules